# dbt check if the model is table or view

Tags: sql, jinja2, dbt

I had a need to verify if the model being worked is view or macro in dbt before applying a logic on a column.

Answer (score 1):

I have used **dbt jinja** templates to solve this

```
{%- set relation = load_relation(this) -%}
{%- if relation.is_table -%}
     alter table if exists {{this}} modify column {{column_name}} ...;
{%- elif relation is not none and relation.is_view -%}
     alter view {{this}} modify column {{column_name}} ...;
{%- endif -%}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `config` object has the materialization. You can look it up directly from there.

```
{%- set materialization = config.get('materialized') -%}
```

Value will be one of `table`, `view`, `incremental`, or `ephemeral`